# nodeos command not found

Tags: nodeos

i have updated today my eosio to version 1.1 and these are the steps that i have took.

- git pull
- ./eosio_build.sh
- cd build
- sudo make install

Everything completed successfully. After this when i try to run EOS locally i get this error

> bash: nodeos: command not found

i looked around for solution but i am not able to fix it. I have run the test and it's failing on

```
Test #32: nodeos_run_test ......................***Failed    0.25 sec
Test #36: restart-scenarios-test-resync ........***Failed    0.33 sec
Test #37: restart-scenarios-test-hard_replay ...***Failed    0.36 sec
Test #39: validate_dirty_db_test ...............***Failed    0.24 sec
Test #40: nodeos_sanity_lr_test ................***Failed    0.31 sec
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4771 answer

Binaries are installed to /usr/local/eosio/bin in the 1.1 release. You'll need to add that path to your PATH environment variable. This is not expected to continue in future releases.

To see why your tests are failing, in your build directory, run ctest --output-on-failure.